# Galera cluster problem after full crash with mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I have a galera cluster with 2 mariadb nodes running. I know that this isn't best practise but I hadn't a chance to do it in another way.

I had a crash and needed to reinitiate the cluster on one node using galera_new_cluster.

The first node a is now running fine, is accessible and the cluster size shows 1 correctly.

But now when I try to start mariadb on the second node b I got the following:

```
    mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.13 database server
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
    Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Tue 2019-12-03 17:19:01 CET; 3h 51min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/

    Dec 03 17:17:31 node-b.my.domain systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.13 database server...
    Dec 03 17:19:01 node-b.my.domain systemd[1]: mariadb.service start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
    Dec 03 17:19:01 node-b.my.domain systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.13 database server.
    Dec 03 17:19:01 node-b.my.domain systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
    Dec 03 17:19:01 node-b.my.domain systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

While this process is trying to start mariadb it fills up my /tmp very quickly.

I tried to enable error logging unsing this in server.cnf:

```
    log-error=/var/log/mariadb.log
```

nothing was logged, I even gave chmod 777 to the file, but still no luck.

I dont know what to do next.

the last times I needed to do galera_new_cluster the second node was starting and connecting to the cluster just fine.

here is the config of node a:

```
    [galera]
    # Mandatory settings
wsrep_on=ON
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://172.17.175.200,172.17.175.201"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='172.17.175.200'
wsrep_node_name='node-a'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=username:password
```

and node b:

```
wsrep_on=ON
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://172.17.175.200,172.17.175.201"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='172.17.175.201'
wsrep_node_name='node-b'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=username:password
```

grastate.dat on node a:

```
version: 2.1
uuid:    da45dbcb-15b9-11e9-b1fc-e7c9d7353265
seqno:   -1
safe_to_bootstrap: 1
```

grastate.dat on node b:

```
version: 2.1
uuid:    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
seqno:   -1
safe_to_bootstrap: 0
```

I checked file permissions on `/tmp` already and they are fine.

thank you for any hints or possible next steps.

Comment: I guess you could try to see what the `mariadb.service` unit tries to do at "start-pre" and why it might time out.

Comment: @mustaccio is pretty much on track - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/#ssts-and-systemd increase the timeout.

Work to fix this automaticly probably needs a newer that systemd-240 version - https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15607

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I got this from command as the failed pre:
`ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR='/usr/bin/galera_recovery'; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=killed, signal=TERM)`
I haven't changed this, its default.